# c# How to write in Microsoft Interop Word

Tags: c#

I am writing my reports directly in microsoft word file, the problem is I cannot write a different text. It just override my other text.

```
 Word.Application myWord = new Word.Application();
        //create the document
        Word.Document myDoc = myWord.Documents.Add();

        //ADD PARAGRAPH
        myDoc.Content.Text = "Identified Market/Visitors" + "         " + "Museum (as a whole)" + "         " + "Percentage" + " ";
        myDoc.Content.Text = "2" + "         " + "76)" + "         " + "25% "+ " ";

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Word Document|*.docx";

        string path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

        myDoc.Close();
```

The second Content Text overrides the First Content Text.
How can I write another line of text?

Comment: strongly recommend you avoid this approach to report writing

Comment: +1 Interop sucks, it's better to use DocumentFormat library to create docx. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK It does not need office installed on the PC.

Comment: If you are working with docx files do not use Microsoft Interop. Use the nuget package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) provided by microsoft instead.

Comment: I think one person saying not to do so is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start next sentence in a new line, just add newline ("\r\n" or Environment.NewLine) to the end of each text:

```
    myDoc.Content.Text = "Identified Market/Visitors" + "         " + "Museum (as a whole)" + "         " + "Percentage" + " " + Environment.NewLine;
    myDoc.Content.Text += "2" + "         " + "76)" + "         " + "25% "+ " " + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: it still overrides my text

Comment: sorry, I missed "+=" on the second line. please see it again.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to generate docx is to use  [OpenXmlSDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK).

The easiest way to write code is to create docx in word which looks like report you want and reverse Enginier C# code from docx using [open xml sdk tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) and not to reinvent the wheel.
[image]

Generated code for your text:

```
   Body body1 = new Body();

    Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphAddition = "008B2DA9", RsidParagraphProperties = "008B2DA9", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "008B2DA9", ParagraphId = "769280AB", TextId = "395E2934" };

    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();

    Tabs tabs1 = new Tabs();
    TabStop tabStop1 = new TabStop(){ Val = TabStopValues.Left, Position = 3686 };
    TabStop tabStop2 = new TabStop(){ Val = TabStopValues.Left, Position = 6804 };

    tabs1.Append(tabStop1);
    tabs1.Append(tabStop2);

    ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
    Languages languages1 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(languages1);

    paragraphProperties1.Append(tabs1);
    paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

    Run run1 = new Run(){ RsidRunProperties = "005F7E61" };

    RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages2 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties1.Append(languages2);
    Text text1 = new Text();
    text1.Text = "Identified Market/Visitors";

    run1.Append(runProperties1);
    run1.Append(text1);

    Run run2 = new Run();

    RunProperties runProperties2 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages3 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties2.Append(languages3);
    TabChar tabChar1 = new TabChar();

    run2.Append(runProperties2);
    run2.Append(tabChar1);

    Run run3 = new Run(){ RsidRunProperties = "005F7E61" };

    RunProperties runProperties3 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages4 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties3.Append(languages4);
    Text text2 = new Text();
    text2.Text = "Museum (as a whole)";

    run3.Append(runProperties3);
    run3.Append(text2);

    Run run4 = new Run();

    RunProperties runProperties4 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages5 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties4.Append(languages5);
    TabChar tabChar2 = new TabChar();

    run4.Append(runProperties4);
    run4.Append(tabChar2);

    Run run5 = new Run(){ RsidRunProperties = "005F7E61" };

    RunProperties runProperties5 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages6 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties5.Append(languages6);
    Text text3 = new Text();
    text3.Text = "Percentage";

    run5.Append(runProperties5);
    run5.Append(text3);

    paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
    paragraph1.Append(run1);
    paragraph1.Append(run2);
    paragraph1.Append(run3);
    paragraph1.Append(run4);
    paragraph1.Append(run5);

    Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "008B2DA9", RsidParagraphAddition = "008B2DA9", RsidParagraphProperties = "008B2DA9", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "008B2DA9", ParagraphId = "6C5F87B4", TextId = "46169FF3" };

    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();

    Tabs tabs2 = new Tabs();
    TabStop tabStop3 = new TabStop(){ Val = TabStopValues.Left, Position = 3686 };
    TabStop tabStop4 = new TabStop(){ Val = TabStopValues.Left, Position = 6804 };

    tabs2.Append(tabStop3);
    tabs2.Append(tabStop4);

    ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties2 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
    Languages languages7 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    paragraphMarkRunProperties2.Append(languages7);

    paragraphProperties2.Append(tabs2);
    paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties2);

    Run run6 = new Run();

    RunProperties runProperties6 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages8 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties6.Append(languages8);
    Text text4 = new Text();
    text4.Text = "2";

    run6.Append(runProperties6);
    run6.Append(text4);

    Run run7 = new Run();

    RunProperties runProperties7 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages9 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties7.Append(languages9);
    TabChar tabChar3 = new TabChar();
    Text text5 = new Text();
    text5.Text = "76";

    run7.Append(runProperties7);
    run7.Append(tabChar3);
    run7.Append(text5);

    Run run8 = new Run();

    RunProperties runProperties8 = new RunProperties();
    Languages languages10 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    runProperties8.Append(languages10);
    TabChar tabChar4 = new TabChar();
    Text text6 = new Text();
    text6.Text = "25%";

    run8.Append(runProperties8);
    run8.Append(tabChar4);
    run8.Append(text6);

    paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
    paragraph2.Append(run6);
    paragraph2.Append(run7);
    paragraph2.Append(run8);

    Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "005F7E61", RsidParagraphAddition = "00BA3985", RsidParagraphProperties = "005F7E61", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "008B2DA9", ParagraphId = "2562476B", TextId = "454E7663" };

    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties3 = new ParagraphProperties();

    ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties3 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
    Languages languages11 = new Languages(){ Val = "en-US" };

    paragraphMarkRunProperties3.Append(languages11);

    paragraphProperties3.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties3);
    BookmarkStart bookmarkStart1 = new BookmarkStart(){ Name = "_GoBack", Id = "0" };
    BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd1 = new BookmarkEnd(){ Id = "0" };

    paragraph3.Append(paragraphProperties3);
    paragraph3.Append(bookmarkStart1);
    paragraph3.Append(bookmarkEnd1);

    SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties(){ RsidRPr = "005F7E61", RsidR = "00BA3985" };
    PageSize pageSize1 = new PageSize(){ Width = (UInt32Value)12240U, Height = (UInt32Value)15840U };
    PageMargin pageMargin1 = new PageMargin(){ Top = 1440, Right = (UInt32Value)1440U, Bottom = 1440, Left = (UInt32Value)1440U, Header = (UInt32Value)720U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
    Columns columns1 = new Columns(){ Space = "720" };
    DocGrid docGrid1 = new DocGrid(){ LinePitch = 360 };

    sectionProperties1.Append(pageSize1);
    sectionProperties1.Append(pageMargin1);
    sectionProperties1.Append(columns1);
    sectionProperties1.Append(docGrid1);

    body1.Append(paragraph1);
    body1.Append(paragraph2);
    body1.Append(paragraph3);
    body1.Append(sectionProperties1);

    document1.Append(body1);
```

PS: Even though it's weird that you build table using string format. Use table in your docx from which you create C# code.